# iOS Push Notifications not working

Tags: java, angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using Ionic 3 with [Ionic Native Push Notifications](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/) on the client and Java [com.notnoop.apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns) on the server.

I can get the Push Notifications to work successfully on an `Android` devise. However, on an `iOS` devise, the client does not display the notification.

**client** (ts)

```
        let topics: string[] = [this.personModelLoggedIn.uid];
        const options: PushOptions = {
          android: {
            senderID: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            sound: "true",
            vibrate: "true",
            topics: topics
          },
          ios: {
            alert: "true",
            badge: false,
            sound: "true"
          },
          windows: {}
        };
        const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);


        pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((data: any) => {
          alert('Received Notification!!! message = ' + data.message);
        });
```

**server** (java)

Android

```
private String sendAndroidPushNotification(String device_token, String topics, String title, String message)
        throws Exception {
    String pushMessage = null;
    if (device_token != null && !device_token.equals("null")) {
        pushMessage = "{\"data\":{\"title\":\"" + title + "\",\"message\":\"" + message + "\"},\"to\":\""
                + device_token + "\"}";
    } else {
        pushMessage = "{\"data\":{\"title\":\"" + title + "\",\"message\":\"" + message + "\"},\"to\": \"/topics/"
                + topics + "\"}";
    }
    // Create connection to send FCM Message request.
    URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + SERVER_KEY);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    // Send FCM message content.
    OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(pushMessage.getBytes());

    return "Android Push Notification: " + conn.getResponseCode() + " " + conn.getResponseMessage() + " - " + pushMessage;
}
```

iOS

```
private String sendIOSPushNotification(String device_token, String topics, String title, String message)
        throws Exception {
    ApnsService service = APNS.newService().withCert(PATH_TO_P12_CERT, CERT_PASSWORD).withSandboxDestination()
            .build();

    String payload = APNS.newPayload()
            // .customFields(map)
            .alertBody(title + " " + message).sound("default").build();

    //service.push(Utilities.encodeHex(topics.getBytes()), payload);
    service.push(device_token), payload);
    return "iOS Push Notification: " + title + " " + message;
}
```

When the above two java methods get called with the appropriate `devise tokens`, the `Android` devise receives a notification, but the `iOS` devise does not.

**Question**

If anyone can advise what's wrong with my `iOS` code (either client or server), I would appreciate your advise.

**UPDATE**

If I try test my APNS on http://pushtry.com/, with my apps `apns-prod-cert.p12`, I get the following:

> Push Notification sent Successfully

And the client does display the notification. So this makes me think there is something wrong with my server code.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
private String sendIOSPushNotification(String device_token, String topics, String title, String message)
        throws Exception {
    ApnsServiceBuilder serviceBuilder = APNS.newService();
        serviceBuilder.withCert(PATH_TO_P12_CERT, CERT_PASSWORD)
                .withProductionDestination();
    ApnsService service = serviceBuilder.build();
    String payload = APNS.newPayload()
            .alertBody(message)
            .alertTitle(title)
            .sound("default")
            .customField("custom", "custom value").build();
    service.push(device_token, payload);

    return "iOS Push Notification: " + title + " " + message;
}
```